OpenCV doesn't read images from some directories
I'm trying to read a 16-bit grayscale PNG with OpenCV. This image is stored on a network share. When I try to load the image with cv.imread() nothing is returned:
import cv2 as cv
print(img_paths[0])
print(type(img_paths[0]))
print(img_paths[0].exists())
img = cv.imread(img_paths[0].as_posix(), cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
print(type(img))

>>> M:\path\to\Meß-ID 1\images\img1.png
>>> <class 'pathlib.WindowsPath'>
>>> True
>>> <class 'NoneType'>

As you can see the file certainly exists. It even is loadable with PIL:
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(img_paths[0])
print(img)

>>> <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=I;16 size=2560x300 at 0x27F77E95940>

And only when I copy the image to the directory of the .ipynb I'm working in, openCV is able to load the image:
import shutil
shutil.copy(img_paths[0], "./test_img.png")
img = cv.imread("./test_img.png", cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
print(type(img))

>>> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Why is OpenCV refusing to load the image?

Try using the full path

can you include the print out of the path?

I've added the path to the question @ARK1375

It's going to be the ß in the path. Use a path with only ASCII symbols.

The first code example has .as_posix(), and the others don't.

pathlib.Path("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop").as_posix() == 'C:/Users/user/Desktop' and windows will tolerate that. probably not an issue. OpenCV not tolerating the ß is an issue for certain.

Yes, OpenCV on Windows has issues with encodings. Usually, anything non-ASCII in the path string can cause you trouble.
Shortest possible solution:
im = cv.imdecode(np.fromfile(the_path, dtype=np.uint8), cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)


Note: choose any suitable IMREAD flag. UNCHANGED is just a suggestion. the default from imread is IMREAD_COLOR_BGR. imdecode has no default.

You could try to convert WindowsPath to string:
img = cv.imread(str(data_height[0]),cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)

Also you could try to decode this image manually:
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

with open(data_height[0],'rb') as f:
    img_bytes = f.read()
    img_array = np.frombuffer(img_bytes,dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv.imdecode(img_array, cv.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)


Converting the WindowsPath to str doesn't work either. Your 2nd solution works, but seems rather cumbersome for something that should just work out-of-the-box.

I've updated my question slightly and changed data_height into img_paths

There is a problem with OpenCV. Seems like OpenCV’s cv.imread() on Windows doesnot support reading images from UNC paths

yes there's a problem. it's been known since forever. opencv's github has issues about this. this same question shows up at least once a month.
